# Generic Diesel implementation of common CRUD methods

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'm struggling with how to utilize Diesel with generics in Rust.  We have a couple of models for persistence in the project I'm working on (Memory, Relational, etc.) that are implemented with a trait that looks like the following:

```
pub trait Persistence<Model>: Send + Sync {
    fn create(&self, model: &Model) -> anyhow::Result<String>;
    // many other common CRUD methods
}
```

One of the concrete implementations of this looks like this:

```
use crate::schema::workspaces::table;

struct WorkspaceRelationalPersistence {}

impl Persistence<Workspace> for WorkspaceRelationalPersistence {
    fn create(&self, workspace: &Workspace) -> anyhow::Result<String> {
        let connection = crate::db::get_connection()?;

        let result: Vec<String> = diesel::insert_into(table)
            .values(workspace)
            .returning(workspaces::id)
            .get_results(&connection)?;
        ...
    }

    // many other common CRUD implementations
}
```

These implementations are almost largely all the same and involve a lot of boilerplate that I'd like to DRY out with a generic implementation like the following with a default generic implementation:

```
trait RelationalPersistence<Model> : Persistence<Model> {
    fn get_table() -> ...;
    fn get_id_column() -> ...;

    fn create(&self, model: &Model) -> anyhow::Result<String> {
        let connection = crate::db::get_connection()?;

        let result: Vec<String> = diesel::insert_into(self.get_table())
            .returning(self.get_id_column())
            .get_results(&connection)?;
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

A couple of questions:

1. Is this (or something like this) feasible or am I being too clever? :)
2. What return types should `get_table` and `get_id_column` have?  I can't seem to work this out from the diesel docs.

Answer (score 0):

Diesel generates a unit struct for the table, which is named by the `table` type within the model's module.  It also generates unit structs for each column.

To make this work with a trait, you need associated types in the trait, bounded by the appropriate diesel traits for tables and columns:

```
use diesel::query_source::Table;
use diesel::expression::{Expression, SelectableExpression, NonAggregate};

trait RelationalPersistence<Model> : Persistence<Model> {
    type Table: Table;
    type IdColumn: Expression + SelectableExpression<Self::Table> + NonAggregate;

    fn get_table() -> Self::Table;
    fn get_id_column() -> Self::IdColumn;

    // ...
}
```

Note that since the unit structs have no data, you could just make them associated constants instead:

```
use diesel::query_source::Table;
use diesel::expression::{Expression, SelectableExpression, NonAggregate};

trait RelationalPersistence<Model> : Persistence<Model> {
    type Table: Table;
    type IdColumn: Expression + SelectableExpression<Self::Table> + NonAggregate;

    const table: Self::Table;
    const id_column: Self::IdColumn;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @cdhowie - that helped a lot in my understanding.  It appears however, that I have to add a whole bunch of other trait bounds to make it work:

Comment: <&'static Model as diesel::Insertable<<Self as RelationalPersistence<Model>>::Table>>::Values:
        UndecoratedInsertRecord<<Self as RelationalPersistence<Model>>::Table>,
    &'static Model: diesel::Insertable<<Self as RelationalPersistence<Model>>::Table>,
    *const str: FromSql<<<Self as RelationalPersistence<Model>>::IdColumn as diesel::Expression>::SqlType,
        Pg,
    >,
    Pg: HasSqlType<
        <<Self as RelationalPersistence<Model>>::IdColumn as diesel::Expression>::SqlType,
    >,
    <Self as RelationalPersistence<Model>>::IdColumn: QueryFragment<Pg>,

Comment: Is there an easier way to express all of this?  As recommended by the compiler it is quite impenetrable as to what it is doing.

Comment: @outside2344 Could you pastebin the compiler error somewhere so I can see the full output?